# Getting incorrect data in a Gridview

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have this application which is suppose to search the sql database for a invoice number. I am using only a textbox, gridview and button. My sql query gives me the correct information when I use the query builder but when I run the application I get over 400 records in the gridview. I am a beginner and I am looking for suggestions and help to get the correct results.
My asp code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtInvoice" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

```
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />

                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SiteID" HeaderText="Site ID" SortExpression="SiteID">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" width="100" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SiteDescription" HeaderText="Site Description" SortExpression="SiteDescription">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="False" width="100"/>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="InvoiceDate" HeaderText="Invoice Date" SortExpression="InvoiceDate">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="False" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="InvoiceNumber" HeaderText="Invoice Number" SortExpression="InvoiceNumber">
                        <HeaderStyle Wrap="True" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="75" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="VendorNumber" HeaderText="Vendor Number" SortExpression="VendorNumber">
                        <HeaderStyle Wrap="True" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="VendorName" HeaderText="Vendor Name" SortExpression="VendorName">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField ="ReceivedDate" HeaderText="Received Date" SortExpression="ReceivedDate">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign ="Center" />
                     </asp:BoundField>

                </Columns>
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OneSourceConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT a.SiteID, a.SiteDescription, po.InvoiceDate, po.InvoiceNumber, v.VendorNumber, v.VendorName, po.ReceivedDate FROM AdmSites AS a INNER JOIN PreTranslations AS pt ON a.SiteID = pt.SiteID INNER JOIN InvAdjustments AS i ON a.AdmSiteID = i.AdmSiteID INNER JOIN PurSitePurchaseOrderHeader AS po ON a.AdmSiteID = po.AdmSiteID INNER JOIN InvVendors AS v ON po.InvVendorID = v.InvVendorID WHERE (po.InvoiceNumber LIKE @InvoiceNumber + N'%')">

                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="InvoiceNumber" Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get connection to the database
        string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OneSourceConnectionString"].ToString();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        conn.Open();
        // Query OneSource Database to grab invoice number
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT a.SiteID, a.SiteDescription, po.InvoiceDate, po.InvoiceNumber, v.VendorNumber, v.VendorName, po.ReceivedDate"
                                        + " FROM AdmSites a, InvVendors v, PurSitePurchaseOrderHeader po, InvAdjustments i, PreTranslations pt"
                                        + " WHERE a.SiteID = pt.SiteID"
                                        + " AND a.AdmSiteID = i.AdmSiteID"
                                        + " AND a.AdmSiteID = po.AdmSiteID"
                                        + " AND v.InvVendorID = po.InvVendorID"
                                        + " AND i.InvoiceNumber = @txtInvoice", conn);

          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtInvoice", txtInvoice.Text);

        try
        {

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            da.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                gvSearch.DataSource = dt;
                gvSearch.DataBind();
            }
            conn.Close();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly are you expecting? You say the results are "incorrect" but you don't say what the correct results should look like

Comment: Why are you using a SqlDataSource and also manually doing a query in your code behind? Do one or the other, not both.

Comment: When I enter a invoice number the grid should show me that record with is attached to that invoice number. When I run the application and I enter an invoice number I get over 400 records.

Comment: The code does not match the query.  The ASP code has where(po.InvoiceNumber LIKE @InvoiceNumber + N'%')  while the code is showing 5 terms in the WHERE.

Comment: you need to dispose of the connection object when you are done.  Better to wrap it in a "using" statement to ensure its cleaned up when your done

Comment: I am new at this and I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: Thanks for the help from everyone. I found my answer somewhere else!

Answer (score 0):

in that your code 
you are using both thing
1)SQL DATASOURCE
" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT a.SiteID, a.SiteDescription, po.InvoiceDate, po.InvoiceNumber, v.VendorNumber, v.VendorName, po.ReceivedDate FROM AdmSites AS a INNER JOIN PreTranslations AS pt ON a.SiteID = pt.SiteID INNER JOIN InvAdjustments AS i ON a.AdmSiteID = i.AdmSiteID INNER JOIN PurSitePurchaseOrderHeader AS po ON a.AdmSiteID = po.AdmSiteID INNER JOIN InvVendors AS v ON po.InvVendorID = v.InvVendorID WHERE (po.InvoiceNumber LIKE @InvoiceNumber + N'%')">

2)SqlCommand 
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT a.SiteID, a.SiteDescription, po.InvoiceDate, po.InvoiceNumber, v.VendorNumber, v.VendorName, po.ReceivedDate"
                                        + " FROM AdmSites a, InvVendors v, PurSitePurchaseOrderHeader po, InvAdjustments i, PreTranslations pt"
                                        + " WHERE a.SiteID = pt.SiteID"
                                        + " AND a.AdmSiteID = i.AdmSiteID"
                                        + " AND a.AdmSiteID = po.AdmSiteID"
                                        + " AND v.InvVendorID = po.InvVendorID"
                                        + " AND i.InvoiceNumber = @txtInvoice", conn);

Don't use both thing 
use only one